# AVPlayer and Uiview animation issue

Tags: ios, core-animation, avplayer, uiviewanimation, avplayerlayer

I have a view controller with 3 components:

1) Tableview

2) UIView (on Tableview)

3) AVPlayerLayer inside UIView

When I scroll tableview I want a resize of UIView and its layer (AVPlayerLayer) and and this I managed to do it.

My problem is that the resize of the view happens in a non-synchronous way with that of the layer while I would like that while the view gets smaller even the layer would follow the shrinking of the view itself.

Here is a video that shows the behavior I get: https://streamable.com/s/z4yc2/eakmvv

This is the viewcontroller's code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lastContentOffset = 0;
    [self setupPlayer];
    [self.table reloadData];
}

-(void)setupPlayer
{
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"testurlvideostreaming"]];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    AVPlayer * avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewStreaming.frame.size.width, self.viewStreaming.frame.size.height);
    [self.avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [self.viewStreaming.layer addSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer];
    [avPlayer play];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound &&
        indexPath.row >= 5 &&
        self.lastContentOffset < tableView.contentOffset.y)
    {
        float percentage = .7f;

        int width = 50;
        int height = width;
        int xPosition = self.viewStreaming.superview.frame.size.width - width;
        int yPosition = self.viewStreaming.superview.frame.size.height * ((1 - percentage) / 2);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

        self.viewStreaming.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewStreaming.frame.size.width, self.viewStreaming.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: nobody can help me?

Comment: hey @Arturi, did you solve that problem?